# Remove busy background from scanned image

Tags: java, image, tesseract

I am trying to use Tesseract OCR for scanning text in an image. However the background is dark and Tesseract is not able to scan thru for the text.

I need help with java code to clear the background gray color from the image.

I have tried below code, where i set the last parameter, Color, as "COLOR.WHITE"  (suggested by someone on this forum but it did not help).

```
    static public BufferedImage scaleImage(BufferedImage img, int width, int height,
        Color background) {
    int imgWidth = img.getWidth();
    int imgHeight = img.getHeight();
    if (imgWidth*height < imgHeight*width) {
        width = imgWidth*height/imgHeight;
    } else {
        height = imgHeight*width/imgWidth;
    }
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
    try {
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        g.setBackground(background);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    } finally {
        g.dispose();
    }
    return newImage;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Tesseract are you using?

Comment: Also, Can you post the image?